# Delete lines with specific pattern

Tags: scripts

I want to delete the line with specific pattern.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   10 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file1-228783-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw------- 1 user1 user1    0 Oct 27 11:17 ./folder1/folder2/.test-file1-228783-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf.lyWfRr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:12 ./folder1/folder2/test-file2-228651-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file3-228706-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw------- 1 user1 user1    0 Oct 27 11:19 ./folder1/folder2/.test-file3-228706-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf.GftyJL
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file4-228695-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file5-228675-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
```

From the above set of lines, want to delete line below

```
-rw------- 1 user1 user1    0 Oct 27 11:17 ./folder1/folder2/.test-file1-228783-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf.lyWfRr
-rw------- 1 user1 user1    0 Oct 27 11:19 ./folder1/folder2/.test-file3-228706-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf.GftyJL
```

Can you please let me know how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Is this something that you want to do only once (now)? Or do you want to do something in a similar way many times, so that you want a shellscript? How would you define the specific pattern?

Comment: do you want to delete these files, or lines from a text file?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete the lines with file name starting with .(dot) and ending with .(dot) + 6 characters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this text is stored in a file, say `ls_l_out.txt`.

I don't know how you want the pattern matching done, but the simplest thing I see is to match the permissions.

So, with that in mind, you can use this sed command:

```
$ sed '/^-rw-------/d' ls_l_out.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   10 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file1-228783-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:12 ./folder1/folder2/test-file2-228651-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file3-228706-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file4-228695-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file5-228675-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
```

If you run that and the output looks good, you can then edit the file in-place with the `-i` flag to sed:

```
$ sed -i '/^-rw-------/d' ls_l_out.txt
```

Comment: That will do. Perfect!!! The patterns I found in filename , .(dot) in front of filename and 6 characters in the end of file name. Looking some regex to match that pattern.

Anyway Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: @mrau In that case, you could match only the lines that end with `.pdf` like this: `sed -n '/\.pdf$/p'`, or delete lines that end with `.pdf.` then six characters: `sed '/\.pdf\..\{6\}$/d'`

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your output that you ran command

```
$ ls -la ./folder1/folder2/
```

or something similar along the lines, and your question asks to parse the output of `ls`. However, you really [shouldn't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), because it's  bad practice for multiple reasons. Better approach would be this:

```
$ ls ./folder1/folder2/{"",.}test*pdf
```

The pathname expansion will grab only files that start with `test` and end with `pdf`, and which may or may not start with a dot. Your files that end with  `lyWfRr` and `GftyJL` wont show up that way.

---

However if you insist on parsing that output, use `$` anchor in `awk` to filter out lines that end only in `.pdf`

```
$ awk '/pdf$/' input.txt                                                                                                                                               
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   10 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file1-228783-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:12 ./folder1/folder2/test-file2-228651-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:08 ./folder1/folder2/test-file3-228706-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file4-228695-cause1-XY-OP-0005.pdf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1   20 Oct 27 10:15 ./folder1/folder2/test-file5-228675-cause1-XY-OP-0001.pdf
```

For the record, I don't condone this, encourage users to avoid `ls` parsing, and do things the Right Way<sup>TM</sup>

Answer (score 0):

While current answers are valid, they might be problematic if you come to work with an extremely large amount of file (over 30k).
In this case I suggest to use find instead:

```
find ./folder1/folder2 -maxdepth 0 -type f -name ".test-file*-*-cause1-XY-OP-*.pdf.*" -delete
```

EDIT: 
I'm assuming you want to delete files and not update the content of a file. In that case, going with sed, awk or grep is the only option and therefore you should avoid this answer.

Comment: Note that it is unclear from the question whether OP wants to delete those files or filter them out from the output of `ls -l`, so it is worth mentioning that `-delete` option that you have at the end of the command there will have consequences.

Comment: Good point, I think OP wants to update the content of a file and not delete a bunch of files.